# Definition of Topology In Terms of Interior Operator

Tags: general-topology

How to rigorously prove the following result?

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $i \colon \mathscr{P}(X) \longrightarrow \mathscr{P}(X)$ satisfy the following properties:

> (i) $i(X) = X$, (ii) $i(A) \subset A$, (iii) $i(A \cup B) = i(A) \cup i(B)$, (iv) $i \big( i(A) \big) = i(A)$.

> Then there exists one and only one topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $X$ such that $i(A)$ will be the $\mathscr{T}$-interior of $A \subset X$.

My Attempt:

We first prove the following auxiliary result:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be any subsets of $X$ such that $A \subset B$. Then we have $i(A) \subset i(B)$.

Proof:

> As $A \subset B$, so we have $B = A \cup (B \setminus A)$, and therefore we also have
> \begin{align}
> i(B) &= i\big( A \cup (B \setminus A) \big) \\
> &= i(A) \cup i(B \setminus A) \qquad [ \mbox{ by (iii) above } ] \\
> &\supset i(A),
> \end{align}
> as required.

> Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the collection of subsets of $X$ defined as follows:
> $$
> \mathscr{T} := \big\{ U \colon U \subset X \mbox{ and } i(U) = U \big\}. \tag{0} 
> $$
> We show that this collection $\mathscr{T}$ is a topology on set $X$.

> As $i(X) = X$ by (i) above, so we can conclude that $X$ is in $\mathscr{T}$.

Am I right?

> As $i(\emptyset) \subset \emptyset$ by (ii) above and as $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set (including the set $i(\emptyset)$), so we can conclude that $i(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and hence that $\emptyset$ is in our collection $\mathscr{T}$. [Refer to (0) above.]

Am I right?

> Let $\mathscr{T}_0$ be any subcollection of $\mathscr{T}$, and let us put
> $$
> S := \cup_{U \in \mathscr{T}_0 } U. \tag{1} 
> $$
> We show that this set $S$ is in our collection $\mathscr{T}$. As every set $U \in \mathscr{T}_0$ is a subset of $X$, so is set $S$. We now show that $i(S) = S$. For any set $U \in \mathscr{T}_0$, as $U$ is in $\mathscr{T}$ and $U \subset S$, so [Refer to (0) above. ] we also have
> $$ U = i(U) \subset i(S)$$
> by our auxiliary result and hence we have
> $$
> S = \cup_{U \in \mathscr{T}_0 } U \subset i(S).
> $$
> But by (ii) we have $i(S) \subset S$. Therefor we have $i(S) = S$. Hence $S$ is in our collection $\mathscr{T}$ as defined in (0) above.

Am I right?

> Let $U_1 \ldots, U_n$ be any sets in $\mathscr{T}$, and let us put
> $$
> U := \cap_{r=1}^n U_r. \tag{2} 
> $$
> We show that this set $U$ is in our collection $\mathscr{T}$. As $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ are all subsets of $X$, so is their intersection $U$. We now show that $i(U) = U$.

How to do this?

One we have shown that then it is easy to show that the topology $\mathscr{T}$ in (0) above is indeed unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By finite induction it remains to show that $i(U\cap U')=U\cap U'$ for $U,U'\in\mathscr{T}$. $$\begin{align}U&=i(U)=i((U\cap U')\cup (U\setminus U'))\\&=i(U\cap U')\cup i(U\setminus U')\\U'&=i(U\cap U')\cup i(U'\setminus U)\\\implies U\cap U'&=i(U\cap U')\cup(i(U'\setminus U)\cap i(U\setminus U'))\end{align}$$But $i(U'\setminus U)\subseteq U'\setminus U$ and $i(U\setminus U')\subseteq U\setminus U'$. These two sets are disjoint, so any intersection of subsets of them will be empty. This shows that: $$U\cap U'=i(U\cap U')\cup\emptyset=i(U\cap U')$$As required.

You are also expected to show that $\mathscr{T}$ is the *only* topology. This can be addressed by a quick remark, but for completeness I suppose it should be made. And yes, your other points are right in my opinion.

Can you see why the above argument fails for infinite intersections? :)

Comment: the argument fails for infinite intersections because we have used (iii) in this finite-intersection argument, and (iii) is not postulated only for finite unions. Am I right?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood $iii)$ actually holds for arbitrary unions if you think about it topologically, I think. But the reason is that there is no way to generalise the logic. The symmetric difference thing ($U\setminus U'$ compared with $U'\setminus U$) only applies to pairs of objects. I could try and use $U\setminus\bigcap_{G\in\mathscr{T_0}}G$ to argue: $$i\left(U\cap\bigcap_{G\in\mathscr{T_0}}\right)=U\cap i\left(\bigcap_{G\in\mathscr{T_0}}\right)$$ (which is true...) but I am no closer to finishing if $\mathscr{T_0}$ is infinite - no matter how many pairs I remove, there are more